# using C# generic property type<T> in an EF code first class

Tags: c#, generics, ef-code-first

For a variety of reasons I have to break my Symbol class into two distinct classes EquitySymbol and CommoditySymbol

In my DailyClose class I was originally using the SymbolId as my foreign key to navigate. I cant do that now that I have broken up Symbol into two different tables.

Here is my original DailyClose class:

```
public class DailyClose
{
    public int DailyCloseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Symbol")]
    public int SymbolId { get; set; }
    public Symbol Symbol {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal TodaysClose { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do which obviously I can't is:

```
public class DailyClose
{
    public int DailyCloseId { get; set; }
    public int SymbolId { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsEquity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal TodaysClose { get; set; }

    public CommoditySymbol CommodSymbol { get; set; }
    public EquitySymbol EquitySymbol { get; set; }

    //constructor
    public DailyClose(int symbolId)
    {
        SymbolId = symbolId;
        if (IsEquity)
        {
            EquitySymbol = new EquitySymbol(SymbolId);
            CommodSymbol = null;
        }
        else
        {
            CommodSymbol = new CommoditySymbol(SymbolId);
            EquitySymbol = null;
        }
    }        
}
```

**Well enable-migrations WAS telling me those types cant be null, but upon closing the solution and reopening it, it now allows my original methodology**

BUT since those types (EquitySymbol & CommoditySymbol) cant be null this won't work. But If I could have a generic property, i.e.  where T is either EquitySymbol or CommoditySymbol based on the IsEquity boolean that would be ideal.

```
 Property<T>
```

and then have

```
public class DailyClose
{
    public int DailyCloseId { get; set; }
    public int SymbolId { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsEquity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal TodaysClose { get; set; }

    public Property<T> WhichSymbolType { get; set; }       

    //constructor
    public DailyClose(int symbolId)
    {
        SymbolId = symbolId;
        if (IsEquity)
        {
            WhichSymbolType = new EquitySymbol(SymbolId);                
        }
        else
        {
            WhichSymbolType = new CommoditySymbol(SymbolId);                
        }
    }
}
```

Is this doable? If it is I'm not seeing how to accomplish this.

Comment: Are `CommodSymbol` and `EquitySymbol` other entities in the database? Why can't they be null?

Comment: Well thats weird, the EF tools were giving me an error when enabling migrations that those types cant be null. I had closed the solution inadverntly and now that its back up, running the migrations work

Comment: This sounds like it would be handled better by having both types implement the same interface and set your WhichSymbolType's type to that interface.